# AskUbuntu is not accessible from Iran

Tags: discussion

It's been a month since AskUbuntu is not accessible from Iran. And I am interested to know why? I can access it through Tor which is not very convenient.

Comment: Iran institutes a firewall on what people in its country can access, similar to china. See here: http://www.neowin.net/news/iran-blocks-vpns-and-more-with-latest-firewall-updates. However, as @ThomasW. said this isn't a question for AskUbuntu but rather Ask Ubuntu Meta or perhaps even Stack Exchange Meta (if you can't get to other sites, such as SO)

Comment: I declined this because I'm a Iranian user in Askubuntu and I didn't see Askubuntu is blocked.

Comment: Maybe this is too localized? Can other Iranian users speak up? Or is there a way to verify whether this problem is only ali's?

Comment: I called my ISP they confirmed the problem and asked me to send them "traceroute" but they also said there is no guarantee it is being fixed. now i'm using VPN and everything works fine. it also seems only i have this problem since my isp can access askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use a VPN instead of Tor? I am currently in Thailand and many of the usual sites that I would visit are blocked since May (due to the Military take over). I tried Tor for a while but found that VPNs (PTPP, L2TP or (best of the lot) OpenVPN) work just as well, and are quicker *and* support BitTorrent.

I use [*Tunnelblick*](https://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/), for OpenVPN, on my MacBook.

Hope this helps.

Good Luck.

P.S. I know that this doesn't *actually* answer the OP's question *"And I would like to know why"*, but I wanted to add the VPN info as a helpful comment, but I am unable to as I am currently lacking in the reputation stakes at the moment.